# Applying a formula until the last row after inserting a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with applying a formula to a column until the last row. The following code will apply to Excel's max row limit (1,048,576 rows).

Here is my code:

```
master.Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'New column 

lastRow = master.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row

master.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,Report!A:BS,71,0),""MISSING"")" 'Perform formula

With master.Range("E1")
     .Value = "Column Name" 
End With
```

However, this issue only occurs when I insert a new column, using the code as follows:

```
master.Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'New column
```

When I am not inserting a new column, I use the following code, which is much faster and also only apply to the last row.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With master.Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,Report!A:N,14,0),""MISSING"")"
End With

With master.Range("J1")
     .Value = "Column Data" 
End With
```

I suspect this is because the code I have written can't understand where the last row in a column is after inserting a blank new one. How would I get around this? The code I use when I need to insert a new column is very slow. I have looked online everywhere and could only find examples similar to the 2nd block of code I have shown. Using xlUp instead of xlDown after inserting a new column will only apply the range up to the second row. I need it to be applied to the last row in relation to the columns around it.

Comment: Why are you basing your lastRow on an empty column instead of one with data (like the A-column or any none-empty one)? You're doing it correctly here `lastRow = master.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` there's no need to change that because you're adding a column.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Yeah but as I said, when I change that line it only applies to the second row due to the formula code,  'J2:J" & lastRow'

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought it was just a different way of typing it out but try this then: `lastRow = master.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` If the A-column is populated, it should let you use it to place your formula in the same amount of rows as the A-column has.

Comment: Are there values in column "A:A"? If yes, the second version should look as you want. If not, calculate the last row on an existing filled column... Your first code is obviously wrong, calculating the last row of an empty column.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Apologies for the wait, this seems to work perfectly! thank you, feel free to put in an answer ill tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lastRow should always be based on a column that's populated, usually the A-column is always populated so then you use:

```
Dim lastRow as Long 'Integer won't cut it with most bigger data sets
lastRow = master.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

If you'd want it based on the E-column, do it before you insert the new column, not after ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, the technique you are using to find the last row will only work if there is data in the column you select. A better method might be to use the Find functionality. Here is the function I use to get LastRow (but note for completely empty sheets it returns the first row)

```
Function lastRow(rg As Variant) As Long
'Find the last row used in a worksheet - regardless of where the data starts and ends
'and regardless of whether the data is contiguous or jagged
'Note use of Variant for the input range parameter
'This allows both worksheets and ranges to passed into the function
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
                    , Lookat:=xlPart _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , searchorder:=xlByRows _
                    , searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        lr = 1  'cater for a completely empty sheet
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    lastRow = lr
End Function
```